# How to decrease the vertical spacing in cases environment?

Tags: align, cases, braces

I have a few lines of code. I want them to align at the equals sign, and also shrink the brace for phi using `cases` environment. The curly brace sticks out at the top and bottom, which is a little unsightly.

I've searched for some suggestions, but none of them solved my problem. For example, they solved the problem here, but ruined the formatting of my paper elsewhere. If you're willing to answer my question, I hope you can notice that I use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.625}`, and in other places in my paper, I also use `cases` and `table` which have strict line spacing requirements. So I hope to make adjustments only for the code of phi and not affect other parts of the paper including the other four formulas in this question.

In addition, these formulas have to be numbered, as shown in the picture, with 6 numbers instead of 8 or other.

```
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.625}
\begin{align}
    \rho _3={}&\left| s\sin \theta -a\cos \theta \right|\\
    z_3={}&s\cos \theta +a\sin \theta -z'\\
    \varphi _3={}&\begin{cases}
    0,\quad s\sin \theta -a\cos \theta \geqslant 0\\
    \pi ,\quad s\sin \theta -a\cos \theta <0\\\end{cases}\\
    \rho _4={}&\left| \left( s'-s \right) \sin \theta -a\cos \theta \right| \label{rho_4}\\
    z_4={}&\left( s'-s \right) \cos \theta +a\sin \theta \label{z_4}\\
    \varphi _4={}&\begin{cases}
    0,\quad \left( s'-s \right) \sin \theta -a\cos \theta \geqslant 0\\
    \pi ,\quad \left( s'-s \right) \sin \theta -a\cos \theta <0\\\end{cases}\label{phi_4}
\end{align}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Just remove the final `\\\`  in each cases environment – they have nothing to do here.

Comment: @Bernard : The final `\\\` really do nothing, but removing it cannot reduce the vertical spacing either.

Comment: Yet,  when I compile, the vertical spacing is not as large as in your image.